# Can't access PHP file from another folder

Tags: php, path, directory

I am trying to access a PHP file that is located in another folder.

```
$path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo $path;
```

It's displaying: 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysqli

I am trying to redirect to welcome_employer.php in the folder "... mysqli/employers".
How can I do this?

```
header('Location:'.$path.'/employers/welcome_employer.php');
```

Thanks

Comment: What output does this give you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the one in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

In particular, the

```
header('Location:'.$path.'/employers/welcome_employer.php');
```

Request will be interpreted, ultimately, by the browser.  So rather then `$path` you need the site's base URL there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use path like

http://localhost/test/test.php

you can't use  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

use  $_SERVER['host']; and then give your directory path